# Why is concurrency level not as high as expected when load testing Apache2 with "ab" ?

Tags: testing, load, apache2, status

I am running Apache2/PHP on my CentOS 5.8 VPS server (2GB RAM, 2GHz processor) and I tried to do a basic load test. Since I am using the standard installation of Apache I assume that prefork model is the one being used. Here is the config:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers      20
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

I did a short test with ab:

ab -q -c 100 -n 10000 mysite.com

In the same time I was checking mysite.com/server-status and I've never seen the number of requests currently being processed exceeding 10. How is this possible ?

According to my calculations the number of concurrent request should have been more than 10, ideally 100. Am I missing something here or Apache 2 server-status is reporting wrong ?

Thank you all.

Comment: Unfortunately the exact environment used when I originally reported the problem is no longer available so I cannot post any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you could see more than 10 requests. You could in fact get more 256 concurrent requests being processed.

However, there's not enough information here to say *why* you didn't see more than 10 connections. Here are some possibilities:

- A slow connection to the host being tested could reduce the number of parallel connections.
- A slow application behind the URL being tested could reduce the number of parallel connections
- Limitations in the /client/ could limit the number of the parallel connections. "ab" should provide some reporting on what level of concurrency it was able to achieve.
- You could accidentally be setting "MaxClients" to a lower value elsewhere in your Apache configuration
- ... or you could have some other Apache configuration problem.

To provide a more specific answer, you could consider posting complete-as-possible copies of your "ab" output and the entire Apache configuration.